# Why does NSMutableDictionary writeToFile return no?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have the following, where path is the documents folder. myArray is an NSMutableDictionary. I'm running this in the simulator.

```
BOOL success = [self.myArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

The above always returns no.  I can see in the target folder that nothing was written.

The path looks like this:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/79D8982F-9995-4831-83B9-E2749F2261CD/Documents/
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `-writeToFilePath:atomically:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect one or more objects within the dictionary cannot be written:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method recursively validates that all the contained
>   objects are property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate,
>   NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the
>   file, and **returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects**,
>   since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

Where *Property List Objects* are (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/PropertyList.html)):

NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSData, NSDate and NSNumber.

Answer (score 2):

The path points to the Documents directory but not to any particular file in that directory. You can't write a file to a directory, you have to give it a file name. The other obvious possibility would be that self.myArray == nil. Plus what Droppy said is absolutely correct.

Comment: The file is on the file path.  I included just the path in the OP.  I'll check the other answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/79D8982F-9995-4831-83B9-E2749F2261CD/Documents/
```

The path just represents a navigation to Documents Directory but not pointing to some kind of file.

Add some file name with the below line and add dictionary to the path

```
NSArray *sandboxArray=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path= [[arr objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.plist"];
```

write something similar to the `path`